# C#: Cannot create delegate because of conditional attribute

Tags: c#, lambda

Here's some simple code illustrating my question:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=JASMINE;Initial Catalog=LouisHowe").LogTo(Debug.WriteLine);
```

This fails with the error: CS1618 Cannot create delegate with 'Debug.WriteLine' because it has a Conditional attribute.

What will work for this is:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=JASMINE;Initial Catalog=LouisHowe").LogTo(log => Debug.WriteLine(log));
```

Why is the first line not allowed? What exactly is going on here that I should understand?

And, how is it log is a Func<> or Action<> but can then be passed to WriteLine(log)?

ps - The example is from Entity Frameworks but I think that is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line will, if the `[Conditional(...)]` value is not met, become:

```
LogTo(log => {})
```

which is fine - a delegate that just does nothing. Although it is probably *more efficient* to bypass that a step higher, i.e.

```cs
#if DEBUG
    optionsBuilder.LogTo(log => Debug.WriteLine(log));
#endif
```

so that in non-debug builds it doesn't constantly invoke a delegate for no useful purpose.

This is not possible in the `LogTo(Debug.WriteLine)` case, because this syntax requires the delegate to be constructed to a specific method-handle, which would mean that it is invoked *regardless* of whether the condition is met. The compiler is simply trying to enforce that the method is only invoked when it is meant to be.

---

You can see the internals of what goes on here by comparing [the compiler output here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQhGOWAPCQAwB8ABACYCWsYALrQLy0CyAngCIxgAVwDmAOgDqURqxgAZRgDsYAbmKkKOGrWVMW7LgBsIoznT6CRE6bIXKYAChOiAlOqIESSWth4ChMUIAb0JacIwAZl8cHwwUWls5RRVHKloAWxgAZ2yAQ1EYV1pggF9w2kJSoA==)

Comment: Oh... it's that the method goes away in release mode. That makes sense. But the other half of the question, how is log which is a Action<> be ok as a parameter to WriteLine(log)? TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen Marc already answered that with the first example. When you are in Debug configuration, the `Debug.WriteLine` command will essentially be removed from your code during compiling. 
In your first case, that leaves your code looking like `.LogTo()`, which is not allowed, since it needs an argument. 
But in your second case it leaves your code looking like `.LogTo(() => {})` which is fine, it will just call an Action without knowing it is actually empty/does nothing.

Comment: @ErroneousFatality My question is how can log be passed as a parameter to WriteLine()? The parameter to WriteLine() is a string or Object. And if an Object it call Object.ToString() on it. As log is an Action<>, how does that work to be the logged parameter?

Comment: @DavidThielen The log is not an Action type. The whole statement `log => Debug.WriteLine(log)` is the Action. Later when it gets converted to non-debug code, the `log => {}` is still an Action, albeit a one that does nothing with the log argument.

Comment: @DavidThielen if you really needed to, you could manually create a delegate to Debug.WriteLine via reflection and the MethodInfo, but: it won't respect `[Conditional (...)]` rules. The compiler considers those rules important, so it refuses to create a direct method-handle delegate - and there is an observable difference (re the Target and Method) between a direct and indirect (meaning: method-body) delegate, so it refuses to fake it by using the second approach. It is merely trying to enforce correctness rules.

Comment: Thank you all for the help on this. It's helped me understand lambda's better.